# I'm tring to make a simple program that changes the innerText to a different word every time i click on it

Tags: javascript

```
const word = document.getElementById("myText");


const randomWords = ["gave","column","judge","hair","single","were",
"such","rather","area","board","black","fence",
"cost","matter","condition","that","slave","record",
"spring","ocean","society","general","central","page",
"successful","divide","community","men","century","did",
"discussion","past","bare","ever","in","brick",
"though","prove","film","unless","reach","complete"]

const randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 40);

word.onclick = function() {
    this.innerText = randomWords[randomNum];
}
```

When i click on my p Element which has the word hi set to it in the html, the word changes to a random word from this list like i expected, but it only does it once. I have to refresh the page and click it again for it to change again when i click on it. Anyone know why?

Comment: You need to select a new `randomNum` each time, inside the click handler.

Comment: The code that runs multiple times is the code inside of your function. You're currently only generating a random number once when the page initially loads, not every time you click (move `const randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 40);` inside of your onclick function)

Comment: Side note: don't hardcode the value `40`. Use `randomWords.length`. This makes it easier to add/remove words from the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `randomNum` variable is only set once. So, every time you click the element, it sets the word to the same index.

Fix this by putting the random number generator inside the onClick, like so:

```
word.onclick = function() {
    var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 40)
    this.innerText = randomWords[randomNum]
}
```

This way, the number will be generated again every time your onClick is triggered.

Also, I'd suggest using `randomWords.length` instead of 40, so that you can add and remove words from the array without breaking your code, like so:

```
var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (randomWords.length))
```